# How to add custom settings to Elasticsearch index from Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, indexing

Need to add custom analyzer to Magento product index settings in Elasticsearch, but how to make this setting permanent? If I modify settings directly in Elasticsearch, Magento overwrites it with the default rules. Don't want to set them globally in Elasticsearch, just for Magento product index.

How such specific indexing settings can be passed to Elasticsearch from Magento?